# How to specify multiple column by xpath

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri

I want to get multiple table data from HTML like this:

```
html = <<EOF
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
</table>
EOF
```

I want to get two data from it like:

```
noko = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
noko.xpath("//tr[1]/td[2]").text #=> "2"
noko.xpath("//tr[1]/td[3]").text #=> "3"
```

What I expect from this code was "23", but it return "123".
How can I get only "23" by using xpath?

```
noko.xpath("//tr[1]/td[2 and 3]").text
```

Comment: concat(//tr[1]/td[2], //tr[1]/td[3])

Comment: You wrote that it returns "123". What returns "123"? Do you mean that the code prints "123", or that one of the calls to `xpath()` returns "123"? I don't see anything in the code you showed that could produce that value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways of solving this problem. One is :

```
require 'nokogiri'

html = <<EOF
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
</table>
EOF

noko = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
p noko.xpath("//tr[1]/td[position()= 2 or position() = 3]").map(&:text).join 
# => 23
# another way
p noko.xpath("//tr[1]/td[2]", "//tr[1]/td[3]").map(&:text).join
# => 23
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're not tied to XPath, you can do it using CSS:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOF)
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
</table>
EOF

td_data = doc.search('tr').map { |tr|
  tr.search('td:nth-child(2), td:nth-child(3)').map(&:text)
}
td_data # => [["2", "3"], ["5", "6"]]
```

Or for older, less incompatible browsers:

```
td_data = doc.search('tr').map { |tr|
  tr.search('td:first-child + td, td:first-child + td + td').map(&:text)
}
td_data # => [["2", "3"], ["5", "6"]]
```

If you need the values returned to be `"23"` and/or `"56"` use:

```
td_data.map(&:join) # => ["23", "56"]
```

though I can't see why that'd be overly useful.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
doc.search('tr[1] td:gt(1)').text
#=> "23"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `position()` to get elements in several different position indexes using xpath, for example :

```
//tr[1]/td[position()=2 or position()=3]
```

You can also use xpath union operator (`|`) to combine multiple xpath expressions, like so :

```
//tr[1]/td[2] | //tr[1]/td[3]
```

I prefer the former way, but union might be the only option in different situation so it's worth mentioning.